# Springboot Jersey - Custom Filter with ServletProperties.FILTER_STATIC_CONTENT_REGEX

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Springboot Application running with a Jersey config line `property(ServletProperties.FILTER_STATIC_CONTENT_REGEX, "/mywebpage/.*")` to enable rendering static html/js/css/image... content for that specific path prefix. All is fine and mywebpage is loading perfectly on `/mywebpage/index.html`.

Now after running `mywebpage` for a few months, we want to redirect a percentage of users (those enabled for a beta) to a new webpage (say https://stackoverflow.com/). So I'm trying to write a `Filter` for the path `/mywebpage/index.html` to redirect the user to the new page if they are enabled for the beta. Now the part that stumped me, is that for some reason, no filters are being invoked for any calls to `/mywebpage/.*` (calls made by the browser to get the html/js/css/... content) (checked with breakpoints and dummy logs). I assume the suspect would be the property `ServletProperties.FILTER_STATIC_CONTENT_REGEX`.

I already have the bit to compute whether the user is beta enabled, and just need to fit it in the `Filter`.

Here's what I was trying:

```java
@Provider
public class RedirectionFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private BetaAudienceService betaAudienceService;

    @Context
    private UriInfo info;

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) throws IOException {
        log.info("Test Log :: Path=" + request.getUriInfo().getAbsolutePath().getPath());
        if (request.getUriInfo().getAbsolutePath().getPath().equals("/mywebpage/index.html") && isBetaEnabled(request)) {
            try {
                request.abortWith(Response.temporaryRedirect(new URI("https://stackoverflow.com/")).build());
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                throw new IOException("Failed to build or respond with Redirection URI", e);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isBetaEnabled(ContainerRequestContext request) { ... }
}
```

and

```java
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appCtx;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setup() {
        register(A.class);
        register(B.class);
        ...
    }

    public JerseyConfig() {
        property(ServletProperties.FILTER_STATIC_CONTENT_REGEX, Constants.STATIC_CONTENT_PATH);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can get around this? Or probably is my approach wrong altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out.

In this case, Jersey is set to run as a `Filter` (since we need to use `ServletProperties.FILTER_STATIC_CONTENT_REGEX`) and Jersey handles all the service requests except for the specific paths `/mywebpage/*` where Jersey is configured to ignore the request due to the static content filter property. Hence those ignored/filtered requests are handled by Springboot directly, which means we can just use a Springboot filter.

Here's the code for the Filter:

```java
public class RedirectionFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter /* can also just `implements Filter` instead */ {

    public static final String REDIRECT_PATH = "/mywebpage/index.html";
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(RedirectionFilter.class);
    private final MyConfig myConfig;

    public UnifiedShellRedirectionFilter(MyConfig myConfig) {
        this.myConfig = myConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.info("Test Log :: Path: " + request.getPathInfo());
        if (isBetaEnabled(request)) {
            response.sendRedirect(myConfig.getRedirectionEndpoint() /* "https://stackoverflow.com/" */);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        log.info("Destructing Filter: " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    private boolean isBetaEnabled(HttpServletRequest request) { ... }
}
```

And put the following in your `@Configuration` class:

```java
    @Bean
//    @Autowired
    public FilterRegistrationBean registerRedirectionFilter(MyConfig myConfig) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registrationBean.setName(RedirectionFilter.class.getSimpleName());
        registrationBean.setFilter(new UnifiedShellRedirectionFilter(myConfig));
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns(RedirectionFilter.REDIRECT_PATH);
        return registrationBean;
    }
```

Comment: Where I referred for writing a Spring Boot Filter -> https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter